# How to drop specific filters in CNN keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

Suppose I have created a model the following way

```
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Flatten, Conv2D

model = Sequential()

model.add(Conv2D(32, kernel_size=(3, 3),
                     activation='relu',
                     input_shape=input_shape,
                     kernel_initializer='he_normal',))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(10, activation='softmax'))
```

After I have finished training the model, how can I drop filters index 1,5 and 9 ? Such that the total remaining filters will be 29 but without the original ones that were located at 1,5 and 9.

I would like to use this "modified model" to predict on the test data again but without those filters

```
score = modified_model.evaluate(x, y)
```

Comment: if you would like to maintain the same trained net you can't... you can't add/drop, you can substitute them with 0 or other number but I'm skeptical about its value

Comment: @MarcoCerliani I am trying to create a new "Modified" trained net based on less filters. I do not care about the current one anymore,

Comment: ok, but would you like to reuse the previous flatten and dense layer trained before?

Comment: yes, I would like to keep the whole network minus those filters that I want to remove

Comment: @MarcoCerliani "..you can substitute them with 0.." can you please show that ? substitute feature map with zero or the filter that creates them with zero ?

Comment: I provide an answer, I hope this can help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is the solution to substitute desired filters in a trained net with zeros

```
inp = Input((10,10,3))
c = Conv2D(32, kernel_size=(3, 3),
           activation='relu',
           kernel_initializer='he_normal')
f = Flatten()
d = Dense(10, activation='softmax')

x = c(inp)
x = f(x)
out = d(x)
model = Model(inp, out)
print(model.summary())

model.fit(.....)

w,b = c.get_weights()
w[:,:,:,1] = 0
w[:,:,:,5] = 0
w[:,:,:,9] = 0
c.set_weights([w,b])
```

about modifying a trained net removing weights is not possible. it's incompatible with the layer below in your case flatten and dense

```
w,b = c.get_weights()
w = np.delete(w, [1,5,9], -1)
b = np.delete(b, [1,5,9], 0)


new_c = Conv2D(29, kernel_size=(3, 3),
               activation='relu',
               kernel_initializer='he_normal',
               trainable=False)

x = new_c(inp)
x = f(x)
out = d(x) # -----> error!
new_model= Model(inp, out)

new_c.set_weights([w,b])

print(new_model.summary())
```

you can create a new network where you manage the old conv2d filters but you have to retrain the layer below

```
w,b = c.get_weights()
w = np.delete(w, [1,5,9], -1)
b = np.delete(b, [1,5,9], 0)

new_inp = Input((10,10,3))
new_c = Conv2D(29, kernel_size=(3, 3),
           activation='relu',
           kernel_initializer='he_normal',
           trainable=False)
new_f = Flatten()
new_d = Dense(10, activation='softmax')

new_x = new_c(new_inp)
new_x = new_f(new_x)
new_out = new_d(new_x)
new_model = Model(new_inp, new_out)

new_c.set_weights([w,b])

print(new_model.summary())

new_model.fit(.....)
```