# TensorFlow optimisation during running model speed up Predict

Tags: tensorflow, keras, optimization, predict

I want to disable a computation of several filters during Predict call with Tensorflow 2 and Keras.

Do i have to modify the source code of Tensorflow to achieve that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer: No, you don't have to modify the Tensorflow source code.

Long answer with example detailled [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61639160/6299772).

Comment: Thanks for your help Noltibus.

But when you set weigths to Zero, filters always computed during predict. And I don't want to retrain my model

Comment: If your goal is to speed up computation, this will do it, since optimization will leave out the 0-weight computations. I'm 99% sure, that there is no other way of leaving out specific filters. You could also try to exclude complete layers, but this would also be done by setting weights to 0, because otherwise input/output dimensions would not match anymore.

Comment: When exclude complete layers your model doesn't work anymore.

Thanks, I will try it.